# Basis of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be given $$M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 6\\
                     2 & 6 & 9 & 18\\
                     1 & 2 & 6 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find the basis of the null space of $M$.

The way I considered it: this matrix has a rank 3.

Pivot=1,2,3
Pivot column=(1,0,0)
Pivot row=(1,2,3,6.)

As far as I know that no. Of pivot and no. Of pivot column/row differs if leading element of row/column is not 1.

Since both pivot column/row are linearly independent, we will take pivot row as a basis (because pivot column after row transformation doesn't span the same vector space).

Am I going wrong??

Comment: Yes, you are. You appear to be confusing the row space with the null space. Check your work: if you transpose that row into a column and multiply it by this matrix, do you get zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let$$ M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 6\\
                     2 & 6 & 9 & 18\\
                     1 & 2 & 6 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$$
The Row Reduction Echelon Form of M is $$ R=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -3\\
                     0 & 1& 0 & 1/2\\
                     0 & 0 & 1& 7/3
\end{pmatrix}$$ Therefore the Null space of M is a one dimensional space. A basis for the Null space is a non-zero vector  V satisfying $$ RV = 0$$ Solving for V results in $$ V=\begin{pmatrix}  3\\
                     -1/2\\
                     -7/3\\1
\end{pmatrix}$$